# Using Linked List to Implement Queue

Tags: java

I am learning Queue in Data Structure, here is the code:

```
public class LinkedListQueue {
    Node first, last;

    private class Node {
        String value;
        Node next;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void enqueue(String v) {
        Node oldLast = last;
        last = new Node();
        last.value = v;
        last.next = null;
        if(this.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("first is null");
            first = last;
            System.out.println("first is " + first.value);
        }else{
            oldLast.next = last;
            System.out.println("first is " + first.value);
            System.out.println("first.next is " + first.next.value);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedListQueue lsq = new LinkedListQueue();
        lsq.enqueue("1");
        lsq.enqueue("2");
        lsq.enqueue("3");
}
```

And the output is like this:

```
first is null
first is 1
first is 1
first.next is 2
first is 1
first.next is 2
```

It works but I don't know where `first.next` is assigned(`dequeue` method is not used and is omitted). It appears to me that after `lsq.enqueue("1")` , the  `first` Node should be `value = "1", next = null` and this remained unchanged because the queue is no longer empty and `first` is never changed in the code. How come `first.next` is 2, or even when I dequeue once, it becomes 3?

Comment: `first.next` is assigned at the first execution of the line `oldLast.next = last`, because in this unique case `first` is equal to `last`.

Comment: Are you required to implement LinkedList?  If not, you can use java.util.LinkedList.  Then, your queue is just a wrapper class that uses a LinkedList..

Comment: @codebod I think I know what you mean. Is it: after the first execution of `enqueue`, `last` and `first` share the same address, whereas in the second execution, line `Node oldLast = last` makes `last`, `first`, `oldLast` share the same address, therefore `first` is actually the same as `oldLast`?

Comment: `last` wouldn't share the same address in the second execution as it is a new node(2) and the line `oldlast.next=last` assigns `first.next` to the node with 2 in this case.